# Installing java - should I use the .rpm file or the .tar.gz?

Tags: ubuntu, java, tar, gzip

I am looking to install java on Linux Ubuntu 64-bit.  Should I use the .tar files or the .gz files.  Download speed is not an issue.  I'm not interested in tons of details I just would like to pick one.  I will be doing application development, though not in java itself which I don't know/use.  It is needed for other products that I run like rubyMine for developing ruby applications.

Comment: you should install it from repository. [here's how](http://openjdk.java.net/install/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If both install and work for you, it doesn't matter which one you choose. both formats accomplish the same thing, and result in the same software being installed.

Another option in Ubuntu is using `apt-get install`, which is very simple, and automates the process.

Comment: I think this covered all the bases and was the best put answer - though it was hard to pick!

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using `apt-get install`, it's cleaner.

Comment: Note, this method does not work for installing specific versions of Java. Often times installing the most up-to-date version of Java is not recommended for production software. At the time of this comment JDK 8 is overwhelming used, while apt-get would install a higher version.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Ubuntu software centre :).

Comment: +1 This is also a good option.  In fact in the past it has got me past command line issues that I was having trouble resolving.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Oracle changed the licence for JDK. You can get only OpenJDK from repository(using apt-get install).

If you want to use Oracle JDK, you should download and install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The .rpm will probably be quicker by a few seconds. It really doesn't matter at all though. A .tar.gz file is just a g-zipped tar file (sometimes called a tarball). The .rpm is a format that Ubuntu knows how to automatically install.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses deb packages. You can use rpm, but I would recommend using the standard repository (e.g. apt-get install openjdk-6-jre). Or you can use the software center in ubuntu.

When using the repository, you will receive updates etc. When using a .tgz or .rpm, you have to manage the updates yourself. Also dependencies will not be resolved automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The rpm id "Redhat Packet Manager" type of file, and is the most easiest to install if you use a compatible system like RedHat or Madrake. You just have to type

```
rpm -iv PACKAGE_NAME.rpm
```

and it will be installed.

A tar file is an archive file which can be extracted by

```
tar -xvf NAME.tar
```

and it will be extracted in the current directory.

Now, a tar.gz file is just a tar file that has additionally been gzipped. This is like WinZip, but it is a format of compression in the Unix systems. First, you have to do

```
gunzip NAME.tar.gz
```

and you get NAME.tar which you will then extract.

The src.tar is a file containing the source code of the application, and if you need the source code for sepearate compilation or modification, you should go for it.

The easiest to use is an rpm file, then a tgz (gzipped tar file), and finally the src file.